# What's Known About the Green's Function to the 1D Diffusion Equation with Position-dependent Diffusion Coefficient?

Tags: parabolic-pde, green-function

Consider a one-dimensional diffusion equation
$$
C(x) \partial_t \Phi(t,x) = \partial_x^2 \Phi(t,x),
$$
on the interval $[0,1]$. The function $C(x)$ has a pole of order 1 at $x=0$ and a pole of finite order (say, 2) at $x=1$.

Questions:

1. Is there a closed-form expression for $\Phi(t,x)$ satisfying the B.C. $\Phi(0,x) = \delta(x-x_0)$, $x_0 \in (0,1)$?
2. If a closed-form expression does not exist, then is there an expansion of $\Phi(t,x)$ for small $t$? For large $t$?

Comment: small comment; if you have a spatially dependent diffusion constant $D(x)$, shouldn't you also have a term with a first-order derivative in $x$, coming from $\nabla_x [D(x)\nabla_x\Phi(t,x)]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The original equation is of the form $ \partial_t \Phi(x,t) = \partial_x^2 \left[ a(x) \Phi(x,t) \right] + \partial_x \left[ b(x) \Phi(x,t) \right] $. I've already done some transformations so as to cast it into the current form. I should have put it more accurately by referring to it as "a heat conduction eq. with a variable conductivity (which vanishes at the boundary points) on a finite interval".

Comment: so you just have a general one-dimensional Fokker-Planck equation; no closed form solutions, see Risken's book: http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9783540615309

Comment: Thanks. So indeed there's no closed-formed solution for the equation. Then what I want instead will be a small-t (asymptotic) expansion for the Green's function. As far as I know, it comes under the name(/category) of "small-time asymptotics of Green's function to heat kernel/diffussion equation". The problem is that results are known (only) for cases where the diffusion coefficient $1/C(x)$ does not vanish anywhere, but now it vanishes at $x=0,1$. I would be glad if anyone could point me to any references available on the topic.

Comment: for small times I would just linearize $C(x)$ around $x_0$; for $t/C(x_0)$ small compared to both $x_0^2$ and $(1-x_0)^2$ that should work, and the singularity at $0,1$ is irrelevant.

Comment: That's right...it means, if a particle starts off at $x_0$, simply replace $C(x)$ with $C(x_0)$, and it's expected (?) the approximation should work for  $t/C(x_0) < x_0^2$ and $t/C(x_0) < (1-x_0)^2$, when the particle has "negligibly small chance" of diffusing to $x=0$ or $x=1$ from $x=x_0$. The problem is I want $\lim_{x_0 \rightarrow 0} \partial_x G_t(x, x_0) $ at $x=0$, where $G_t(x,x_0)$ is the Green's function, and $t$ is small.